# Replace '\' with '/' in a String C# WinForm App

Tags: c#, winforms, string

Can anyone please suggest a way to replace back-slash '\' with slash '/' in a string. Basically the string is a path. I have tried using Replace() method of string, but its not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to capture the result of the `Replace` (strings are immutable), and ensure you use character-escaping for the `\`:

```
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
path = path.Replace("\\", "/");
```

For info; most of the inbuilt methods will accept either, and assuming you are on Windows, `\` would be more common anyway. If you want a uri, then use a `Uri`:

```
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
Uri uri = new Uri(path); // displays as "file:///C:/Users/mgravell/AppData/Local/Temporary Projects/ConsoleApplication1/bin/Debug"
string abs = uri.AbsolutePath; // "C:/Users/mgravell/AppData/Local/Temporary%20Projects/ConsoleApplication1/bin/Debug"
```

Comment: You need sitePath =sitePath.Replace("\\", "/"); as .Replace createa a new instance

Comment: I think you need to do the following: sitePath = sitePath.Replace("\\", "/"); This is what Marc means when he says strings are immutable, calling a function does not change the value of the string, the function returns a new string.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was missing the point that String are immutable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have answered all my questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is only slightly related, but I like to mention it when I see the \ character being used; just in case some are unaware.

Note that C# has a syntax escape character, the @ symbol. You can use it to escape reserved words, but more often, you'll use it to escape string literal escape sequences.

For example, if you're going to use the \ character in a literal and don't want to have to escape it with another \, you can prefix the literal with @.  Thus the above code could be written like:

```
path = path.Replace(@"\", "/")
```

I find it very helpful when working with file paths:

```
var path = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\My Documents\\SomeFile.txt";
```

can be written as:

```
var path = @"C:\Documents and Settings\My Documents\SomeFile.txt";
```

It helps the readability.